# Enable to start the activity for application lock APP

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Developing an application to get the list of APPS installed, with two buttons one is enable passcode and other is change passcode, Change passcode button will be hidden if app not locked, when i click button i am not able to get passcode options,

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    btOnOff = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_on_off);

    btOnOff.setText(R.string.enable_passcode);
    btOnOff.setOnClickListener(this);

    btChange = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_change);
    btChange.setText(R.string.change_passcode);
    btChange.setOnClickListener(this);

     update();


    packageManager = getPackageManager();
    List<PackageInfo> packageList = packageManager
            .getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);

    List<PackageInfo> packageList1 = new ArrayList<PackageInfo>();

    }
    apkList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.applist);
    apkList.setAdapter(new ApkAdapter(this, packageList1, packageManager));
}


@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    if (view.equals(btOnOff)) {
        int type = LockManager.getInstance().getAppLock().isPasscodeSet() ? AppLock.DISABLE_PASSLOCK
                : AppLock.ENABLE_PASSLOCK;
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AppLockActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(AppLock.TYPE, type);
        startActivityForResult(intent, type);

    } else if (view.equals(btChange)) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AppLockActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(AppLock.TYPE, AppLock.CHANGE_PASSWORD);
        intent.putExtra(AppLock.MESSAGE,
                getString(R.string.enter_old_passcode));
        startActivityForResult(intent, AppLock.CHANGE_PASSWORD);

    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
    case AppLock.DISABLE_PASSLOCK:
        break;
    case AppLock.ENABLE_PASSLOCK:
    case AppLock.CHANGE_PASSWORD:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.setup_passcode),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    updateUI();
}
private void updateUI() {
    if (LockManager.getInstance().getAppLock().isPasscodeSet()) {
        btOnOff.setText(R.string.disable_passcode);
        btChange.setEnabled(true);
    } else {
        btOnOff.setText(R.string.enable_passcode);
        btChange.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

} 
In what way i have to set clicklistener for two buttons ?

This is the error 
[image]

i am not able to start the activity . kindly suggest me in different way if this is wrong

Comment: You've got a `NullPointerException` in `onCreate()`. If you look further down in the stack trace, it will tell you the exact line number where the `NullPointerException` is occurring.

Comment: Without seeing your code, I'm guessing that one of the `findViewById()` calls is failing and returning `null`.